# bzdecompress empty string

Tags: php, zip

I would like to use curl to post data from one server to another.
I cannot use anything else like put for example - I cannot change apache settings and it's not allowed on my server. That's the reason I would like to do it with post.

I have following code:

```
if (!empty($_POST)) {
    //let's see what's posted
    var_dump($_POST);

    //unzip data
    retrieveData($_POST);
}

function retrieveData($post)
{
    $output = false;
    if (isset($post['data'])) {
        if (isset($post['zipped']) && $post['zipped'] == true) {
            $output = bzdecompress ($post['data']);

            var_dump($output);
        }
    }
    return $output;
}
```

result is

```
array(2) { ["data"]=> string(7) "BZh41AY" ["zipped"]=> string(1) "1" } 
string(0) ""
```

as you can see I get an empty string from bzdecompress function. Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem was with encoding chars and not the `bzdecompress` function. 
I don't have to `urlencode` and `urldecode` characters in POST method.